# How Do I Make Metal Post Attachable for Neighbor

Tags: fence

I'm in the process of building our backyard fence. We agreed with the neighbor to use metal posts. One problem I haven't solved is where our back corners meet. There will be 3 panels attached here. One that makes up part of the fence between our yards, one that starts the backside of my yard, and one that starts the backside of his yard.

We've been joining panels with wooden beams and pipe grip ties so far. We figured we would be able to find a tie that terminates/ends the fence for the neighbor to build from, but I can't find any such product. All the ties I see have 2 wings. There are no 1- or 3- winged ties to be found.

What do people normally use?

Comment: Please [edit] to add pictures. There are MANY types and styles of "metal posts" so it's really hard to envision exactly what type yours are, which will impact possible solutions.

Comment: Four way or three way structural pipe fitting?  https://www.easyfit.com/catalog/ef24g-4-way-with-center-tube-structural-pipe-fitting - https://www.easyfit.com/catalog/ef23g-side-outlet-tee-structural-pipe-fitting

Comment: @Ecnerwal Will do. I'll tag you once updated.